# Как сделать несколько секций строго в линию в Elementor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, elementor

У меня есть две секций в элементоре. В первой секций логотип сайта, во второй главное меню. На телефонах, вторая секция как бы переносится на другую строку. Это происходит даже если я полностью уменьшу логотип в первой секций. Что делать? Как сделать, чтобы вторая секция была на уровне первой?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то, вопрос по CSS. Для того, чтобы "перенести" блоки на следующую строку, им ставят `width=100%`. Правила выглядят примерно так:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
.uael-post__columns-mobile-1 .uael-post-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Вам надо найти такие правила и отменить их.